# Is there a good general methodology for wrapping swig generated classes in ruby?

Tags: c++, ruby, swig

I have used SWIG to generate wrappers for a C++ library that I am going to be using in ruby.

Since it was a C++ library the method names are not "ruby like", ie they are camelCase for example. I also will need to add some of my own methods, operators for example.

So I was thinking about creating ruby classes to wrap the SWIG classes, but wanted to keep it simple.  Here is what I was thinking of doing, unless someone can point me in a better direction.

I created this "method wrapper" method which I would use to call the corresponding swig generated method from it's corresponding ruby meth in the new ruby class.

I am making use of ruby's scheme of getting the method via

```
some_method = SomeClass.method(:some_method_name)
```

and then calling it later on via

```
some_method.call
```

Are there any issues with that plan?

Here is my method wrapper method:

```
def method_wrapper(target_method, hash_keys,  args=[])
 if args.length == 0
    #puts "calling without args"
    return_value = target_method.call
 else
    if args[0].class == Hash
      method_args = Array.new
      hash_args = args[0]
      hash_keys.each do |key|
        arg_value = hash_args[key]
        method_args << arg_value if arg_value
      end
      #puts "calling with hash args #{method_args}"
      return_value = target_method.call(*method_args)
    else
      #puts "calling with args"
      retrun_value = target_method.call(*args)
    end
  end
  return return_value
end
```

and here is how I would use it to wrap each method in the SWIG generated class

```
class RubyClassName
  def ruby_method_name(*args)
    return method_wrapper(Swig_module_name::SwigClassName.method(:swigMethodName), [:ruby_hash_key_arg1, :ruby_hash_key_arg2], args)
  end
end
```

then I can call the methods like such

```
RubyClassName.ruby_method_name
RubyClassName.ruby_method_name some_value
RubyClassName.ruby_method_name(some_value1, some_value2)
RubyClassName.ruby_method_name :ruby_hash_key_arg1 => some_value
RubyClassName.ruby_method_name :ruby_hash_key_arg2 => some_value2, :ruby_hash_key_arg1 => some_value1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use %rename directive for renaming C++ classes and functions to something else (for example, rename FooBar to fooBar or foo_bar).

You can use %extend to add your own operators and such.

I believe the above will support all the call examples you had, without needing a second layer of wrapping.

Comment: I read about the rename directive, I will have to read about extend.  I had read here that a lot of times people will create these wrapper ruby classes even if it is just to document the api.  You think it is best to avoid adding the extra layer?

Comment: I favor fewer layers; less chance for bugs. But there is certainly value in documenting an exported API; SWIG does not support that so I have always seen exporter of API refer user to the C++ docs and they can usually figure out how to use it. But if you add a lot of your own methods, the C++ docs won't be sufficient. What documentation tool do you use? In Python we have sphinx, which makes it easy to document classes without editing the code.

Comment: I used the rename directive and it did pretty much what I wanted